# Vertically expand textbox automatically when text is too long

Tags: wpf, textbox, resize

I am trying to mimic the Sticky Notes application in Windows 7. In the original application, if you type text into a Sticky Note and the text becomes too large (vertically, as in number of lines) to fit in the window, the window automatically expands vertically, one line at a time, to allow for more room. In other words, where in a normal Textbox a vertical scrollbar would appear and the text would scroll down (so that the first line becomes invisible), in the Sticky Notes the textbox expands exactly enough to fit the text so that no scrollbar appears. The scrollbar still appears when you manually resize the window afterwards, of course.

If you have Windows 7 just open the Sticky Notes application and type a few lines in the sticky note until it enlarges.

I am trying to mimic this effect but I'm having no luck. The problem seems that the actual Window should resize, not just the Textbox (I don't think WPF works this way, that a resize of a child element can 'force' the parent element to become larger? At least not for a Window, right?).

The contents of the Window at this point are such:

```
<Window Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"> 
    <!-- Transparent border to draw dropshadow on -->
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <!-- Grid with UI elements -->
        <Grid Margin="5" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="27" />       
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 

            <!-- Stickynote header -->
            <Border ... />

            <!-- Content -->
            <Border Grid.Row="1">

                <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentText}" ... />

            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve this effect? Thanks!

Comment: Try to set Width="Auto" for textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Window Property `SizeToContent="Height"`

*Sample*

```
<Window ...
        MaxHeight="500"
        SizeToContent="Height">
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <Grid Margin="5" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="27" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" MinHeight="100"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

---

**Edit**
To use it with the `TransparentWindow` you posted, add `transparentWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual` in `OnDragDelta` (TransparentWindow.cs)

```
private static void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    TransparentWindow transparentWindow = (TransparentWindow)sender;
    Thumb thumb = e.OriginalSource as Thumb;
    transparentWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
    if (thumb != null && transparentWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, but there's a major issue: I cannot resize the window manually anymore now (at least not vertically). It seems to be a problem with my window, I am using this 'transparent' resizable borderless window code (my window inherits TransparentWindow): http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/getwpfcodebywillhan/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1578 
It works fine with a regular Window, but for some reason this custom resizable window won't work. Is it because it's setting the Height property manually maybe? I have no clue...

Comment: Updated my answer. For that subclassed Window you need to reset `SizeToContent` to `Manual` when resizing. Try it out and let me know if it gives you the desired result

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it could work. I can't test it until later today, I'll let you know.